# have a hard time of things

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The difficulty of all colored “firsts” is well documented or at the
> very least easily imaginable, and need not be elaborated except to say
> that Pompey had an exceedingly hard time of things.

This is from *The Intuitionist* by Colson Whitehead. Does “have a hard time of things” mean same as when just saying “have a hard time”? Or is there another meaning?

Comment: The official guidelines say this as well, but I can only be most helpful if you give more context. A link to the relevant text, or a more detailed description of what’s going on, would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Having a hard time of things" is an idiomatic way of saying someone is experiencing a troubling period, perhaps due to several factors.

This may be chiefly American English, as in British English I'm more used to hearing "*[a hard time of it](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-danish/a-hard-time-of-it)*", which means the same. To denote an extended period, some might even say "he's had a hard time of it *of late*".

In some contexts it could simply be said as "a hard time" without altering the meaning - you'll notice that Cambridge contains an example where "of it" is in parenthesis, but including these words does tend to imply more than just one specific troubling thing.